# How to redirect page after saving the form to the database using Laravel?

Tags: php, url, laravel

I have a problem with this. I am studying Laravel and I am building a form. My simple scenario is like this. After the user finished his/her registration form they need to click the submit button. Then if there's a validation it should display and the form should not save. If there are no error it should save. And redirect to home page. My error is this, after saving the data in the database I can't redirect the page to the index. It will display an error 403 forbidden page.

Here's the code in my routes:

```
Route::model('employee','Employee');

Route::get('/','EmployeesController@index');
Route::get('/register', 'EmployeesController@register');
Route::get('/handleRegister', 'EmployeesController@handleRegister');

Route::post('/handleRegister', function() 
    {

        $rules = array(
            'emp_code'      =>  'numeric',
            'lastname'      =>  'required|min:2|max:15',
            'firstname'     =>  'required|min:2|max:20',
            'middlename'    =>  'min:2|max:20',
            'password'      =>  'required|min:8|max:30',
            'cpassword'     =>  'required|same:password'
        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if($validator->fails()) {

            $messages = $validator->messages();

            return Redirect::to('register')
                                ->withErrors($messages)
                                ->withInput(Input::except('password','cpassword'));

        } else {

            $employee = neW Employee;

            $employee->emp_code     = Input::get('emp_code');
            $employee->lastname     = Input::get('lastname');
            $employee->firstname    = Input::get('firstname');
            $employee->middlename   = Input::get('middlename');
            $employee->gender       = Input::get('gender');
            $employee->birthday     = Input::get('birthday');
            $employee->password     = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

            $employee->save();

            return Redirect::action('EmployeesController@index');

        }

    }
);
```

Here's my index function:

```
public function index()
    {
        return View::make('index', array(
            'page_title'    => 'Flax: Food Ordering',
            'login_footer'  => 'Flax Inc. @ '. date('Y'),
            'register_link' => action('EmployeesController@register')
        ));
    }
```

Then in my browser I have this:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /http://dev.flax_order.local on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.0.1g PHP/5.5.12 Server at dev.flax_order.local Port 80
```

In the URL I noticed this:

```
http://dev.flax_order.local/http://dev.flax_order.local
```

It doubles the link.

I don't know where's my error. Can you help me with this?

By the way here's the routes from running

```
php artisan routes

C:\wamp\vhosts\flax_order>php artisan routes
+--------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                 | Name | Action                       | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /          |      | EmployeesController@index    |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD register   |      | EmployeesController@register |                |               |
|        | POST handleRegister |      | Closure                      |                |               |
+--------+---------------------+------+------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: put your routes file and index action.

Comment: The code for EmployeesController@index is in the top it's my index function. I included that in my question

Comment: I removed that but still same effect

Comment: this is NOT a laravel error. it is a apache error. what is your htaccess file? it clearly says you don't have the permission.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to change

```
return Redirect::action('EmployeesController@index');
```

into:

```
return Redirect::to('/');
```

Although I don't see error here maybe underscore in hostname causes this problem.

Comment: Ok I have a result like this:
`InvalidArgumentException 
Route [/] not defined.`

Comment: Ok, run `php artisan routes` in console and show your routes (edit your question)

Comment: Ok the underscore is my problem. I don't know why but when I changed my vhosts name it worked. Thanks for the informatiom

Comment: @Jerielle Underscore are not allowed in domain names so probably Laravel think underscore is a part of url and not host